# How do i filter values so that my graph are not clustered

Tags: r

I am working on a particular dataset and after doing a box plot using ggplot my results came to be a bit clustered. I used the coord flip function to make it easier to read but it is still hard to read. i have tried to use the filter function to remove values that are less than 2 so that i can focus on the results that have higher values (which is the focus of the project) but for some reason its giving me an error. is there a specific way of using the filter function or any other function to show values that are higher than 2?

```
Log_data %>%
  Filter(Log_data$Data.Value > 2 ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Data.Value, Element.Name, colour = Scale.Name))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x= "Scale ",
         y= "Abilities ", 
         title= " Logistician")
```

[image]

Comment: The error is that it can't find the file you're referencing to import into R